# Holidays in Calendar

Tags: office-365, calendar, sharepoint-calendar

Is there any way to see the federal holidays holidays (easter, christmas, etc.) in the SharePoint calendar in Office 365?

According to this post "[SharePoint Holiday calendar](http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/148/t/188819.aspx)" from 2013 it was not possible, but there was a workaround. Has this function already been implemented by now?

Answer (score 3):

It is not implemented and I don't see they will be doing it on priority. The reason being SharePoint is a global product and it is being used world wide. Hence targeting US holidays only helps customers in US.

You can try the workaround suggested by creating a Shared Mailbox Calendar and overlaying it to SharePoint.

Comment: It this also possible online (in the browser) using Office 365, only? I don't have standalone Office on my machine installed.

Comment: Yes you can do this through the UI. The only thing matters is that exchange server should be accessible on internet.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to manually add the holidays you want to any given calendar and use the repeating patterns to accomplish this. I agree with @Amal Hashim's post as there were not added to the product for many reasons.

1. Set the holiday to an all day event
2. Enable Recurrence
3. Select Yearly
4. Choose a repeating pattern
5. Choose a start day for this repeating series. (prior to the first holiday you want to see)
6. Select No End Date

[image]